# Finding a string in another string

Tags: actionscript-3

Using actionscript, how do I find if the following string contains the substring  `assets/Wallpaper`?

```
http://virtual.c7beta.com/assets/Wallpaper/default.jp&session_id=1fb764b01a2843763a76316a6c85313a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[indexOf](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary692.html) is your friend. It tells you the first occurence of a string in another string ( and even if there is none. )